# How do I stop segmentation error with array in C++?

Tags: c++

I am creating a simple command line, tic-tac-toe game in C++. Whenever I reun the code I get no compiler errors but then VSCode tells me once I have given input that there is a Segmentation Fault. I will paste my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void print_board(string board[3][3])
{
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[0][0] << "  |  " << board[0][1] << "  |  " << board[0][2] << "  " << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[1][0] << "  |  " << board[1][1] << "  |  " << board[1][2] << "  " << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[2][0] << "  |  " << board[2][1] << "  |  " << board[2][2] << "  " << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
}
string turn(string board[3][3], bool xturn)
{
    int position;
    cout << "Where would you like to go (1 - 9): ";
    cin >> position;
    if (xturn)
    {
        string player_turn = "X";
    }
    else
    {
        string player_turn = "O";
    }
    board[(int)floor(position / 3)][(position % 3) - 1] = "X";
    return board[3][3];
}
int main(void)
{
    string board[3][3] = {{" ", " ", " "}, {" ", " ", " "}, {" ", " ", " "}};
    bool xturn = true;
    while (true)
    {
        print_board(board);
        board[3][3] = turn(board, xturn);
        xturn = !xturn;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is much is much appreciated. Thanks! If it helps I am using the GCC compiler.

Comment: `(position % 3) - 1` ? `-1` is not a valid index

Comment: `return board[3][3];` accesses out of bounds

Comment: Arrays are 0 indexed, [3][3] will be out of bounds.

Comment: `return board[3][3];` goes out of array bounds, no matter what.

Comment: `if (xturn) { string player_turn = "X"; ...` has no effect whatsoever. You need to write less code and test more. This code has more than 1 problems

Comment: There is no point in converting `position / 3` to floating-point with `floor` and then casting it to `int` - it already is an `int`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Do you mean more than one problem?

Comment: @molbdnilo I need to cast it to an int because it was a double from dividing it - it gives an error if I don't

Comment: `position/3` is not a `double`, it is an `int` (since both `position` and `3` are `int`s). You made the mistake of assuming that it isn't an integer, and that you needed to `floor` it. Read about integer division in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void print_board(string board[3][3])
```

why are you using a string[3][3] ? you basically just need a 3x3 character array

---

```
board[(int)floor(position / 3)][(position % 3) - 1] = "X";
```

make sure you keep yourself in range 0..2, -1 is outside and will
cause undefined behavior

---

```
return board[3][3];
```

No that is wrong in more ways than one, and in any case there is no need to return a copy

---

```
board[3][3] = turn(board, xturn);
```

this will not go well, you return a board of 3x3 strings but assign
it to at best, an undefined place.

since you already pass the address of the board to your turn function, that is that is all needed. change it in place.

---

```
turn(board, xturn);
```

---

arrays are addresses in memory, it is the starting address where in memory some data is stored

if you pass an array/matrix to a function you are letting the function know where in memory it is stored, so any changes to the array/matrix will be done in place, therefore you do not need to return a copy.

Comment: " you seem to only able to put values in {0,0},{1,1},{2,2}" , `turn` lets the user do their turn on any of the 9 tiles, by asking for a number in [1,9]

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ah that is true, edited. good catch